# How do I get the estimator key reference to OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()) for GridSearchCV() in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am doing grid search for the hyper-parameters for `GridSearchCV` in scikit-learn.

This is how I prepared the ML algorithms and their associated parameters to be searched. The `LogisticRegression()` and `RandomForestClassifier()` are specified with their correct estimator keys `logisticregression__` and `randomforestclassifier__`, respectively.

```
ml_algo_param_dict = \
                {   'LR_OVR': {'clf': LogisticRegression(),
                                'param': [{
                                    'logisticregression__solver': ['lbfgs', 'liblinear'],
                                    'logisticregression__penalty': ['l2'],
                                    'logisticregression__C': [0.1, 1, 10],
                                    'logisticregression__class_weight': [None],
                                    'logisticregression__multi_class': ['ovr'],
                                    'logisticregression__max_iter': [1000, 4000],
                                }, {
                                    'logisticregression__solver': ['newton-cg'],
                                    'logisticregression__penalty': ['l2'],
                                    'logisticregression__C': [0.1, 1, 10],
                                    'logisticregression__class_weight': [None],
                                    'logisticregression__multi_class': ['ovr'],
                                    'logisticregression__max_iter': [1000, 4000],
                                }]},
                    'RF_OVR': {'clf': RandomForestClassifier(),
                                'param': [{
                                    'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [100],
                                    'randomforestclassifier__max_depth': [150, 200],
                                    'randomforestclassifier__random_state': [888],
                                }]},
                    'SVC_OVR': {'clf': OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()),
                                'param': [{
                                        'onevsrestclassifier_linearsvc__C': [100],
                                        'onevsrestclassifier_linearsvc__max_iter': [400, 6000],
                                }]},
```

But what about `OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())`? I tried many ways (ie, `onevsrestclassifier_linearsvc__`, `onevsrestclassifier__`, `linearsvc__`), but kept getting the error `Check the list of available parameters with estimator.get_params().keys()`. How can I find out the right estimator key?

---

Added the following code to show how the dict is used

```
transformer_num = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

transformer_cat = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='')),
    ('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', transformer_num, feature_list_num),
        ('cat', transformer_cat, feature_list_cat),
        ])

for algo_key, algo_val in ml_algo_param_dict.items():
    f1 = make_scorer(f1_score , average='micro')
    pipe = make_pipeline(preprocessor, algo_val['clf'])
    grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, algo_val['param'], n_jobs=-1, cv=5, scoring=f1, refit=True)
    grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I have tried `'onevsrestclassifier_linearsvc__C', onevsrestclassifier_linearsvc_estimator__C', 'onevsrestclassifier__C', 'linearsvc__C', 'onevsrestclassifier__linearsvc__C', 'onevsrestclassifier-linearsvc__C', 'onevsrestclassifier_linearsvc_estimator__C', 'estimator__C'`, but all gave me the same error `Check the list of available parameters with "estimator.get_params().keys()"`.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the referenced naming that is working without error:

```
'SVC_OVR': {'clf': OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()),
            'param': [{
                'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__C': [1, 10],
                'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__max_iter': [10000],
                      }]},
```